# cmdlet as input to another

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell command for replacing in a file:

```psh
(Get-Content c:\myfile.txt) | ForEach-Object {
  $_ -replace "date is x", "date is 2015.02.29"
} | Set-Content c:\myfile.txt
```

I want the hardcoded date (2015.02.29) to come from another cmdlet:

```psh
(Get-Date -format yyyy.MM.dd)
```

How would I inject this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your hardcoded value with your command:

```psh
(Get-Content c:\myfile.txt) | ForEach-Object {
  $_ -replace "date is x", "date is $(Get-Date -format yyyy.MM.dd)"
} | Set-Content c:\myfile.txt
```

Comment: No, with your suggestion the command is just treated as a string and not executed to produce a date.

Comment: Since the file is read in a subexpression, the loop is not required: `(Get-Content c:\myfile.txt) -replace "date is x", "date is $(Get-Date -format yyyy.MM.dd)" | Set-Content c:\myfile.txt`. Might also be a good idea to calculate the date just once and store it in a variable, to avoid corner cases like "date changes while script is running".